# Overriding the layout for HTML Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the html button to look like the image below. Is there way to change its layout without using any html element?

**UPDATED:** In the normal button, there is only one text node, but in this case there are two text nodes.

[image]

Comment: Post the html & css code

Comment: ^ Agreed. We have no idea how it currently looks. So we can't tell you what you to change.

Comment: I want all the buttons to be look like the image above. Yes, all the buttons!

Comment: I mean, is there a way to override its layout?

Comment: Consider posting your html code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure with statement "without using any html element", but you can just styling it using css(anything you want), see **example** below:

**Code:**

```css
.myButton {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #6ED7DB;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton">INFO
  <br/>IRO4</button>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/cws80ujr/2/)

Comment: If you look at the button above, It has two text nodes, unlike the normal button which has only one. Im asking if there is a way to overide the contents of the normal button.

Comment: @EthylCasin , instead of input button, you can use `<button class="myButton">INFO<br/>IRO4</button>`

Comment: You better post it as your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CSS` if you want to change the style of the button, and use this selector (`input[type="button"]`) if you want it to change all the button using the same style.

```css
input[type="button"] {
  background:violet;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **example** below:

**Code:**

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
    display: block;
    background: #6ED7DB;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration; none;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">
    <p>INFO</p>
    <h1>IR04</h1>
</a>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/biplobice/rsy8d0fg/)